# Почему такой приоритет операций в Java

Tags: java

```
int number = 2;
System.out.println(number + number * (number + ++number));
System.out.println(number);
```

Почему на экран будет выведено 12, а не 18. Немного не понимаю, number же увеличивается в скобках.
Почему еще у унарных операторов ассоциативность справа налево? Как это работает?

Comment: Потому что при вычислении выражения `number` выбирается из памяти один раз и с этим значением проводятся все вычисления

Comment: int a = 3;
        int b = ++a + (a-- * ++a);

Comment: @avp а почему тогда, в примере выше, там все значения меняются?

Comment: В смысле, почему `a` после вычисления увеличивается на 1?

Comment: @avp вы говорите, что в вопросе number выбирается из памяти один раз со значением 2 и с ним происходит работа. То есть number во всей операции равно 2. Но после становится равным 3.
Но тогда почему в примере выше, где a=3 в процессе вычислений, а несколько раз меняется, и принимает значения, сначала 3, потом 2, потом 4, то есть 4*(3*2). Вот такой вот вопрос

Comment: Хотите сказать, что в `a = 3; b = ++a + (a-- * ++a);` не b не равно `4 + (3 * 4)`  = 16 и `a` после вычислений не равно 4? (если так, то странно)

Answer (score 2):

Есть три вещи, которые важно не путать:

1. приоритет операций
2. ассоциативность операций
3. порядок вычисления подвыражений

Рассмотрим на примере выражения `a / b / c - d`.

Приоритет и ассоциативность задают правила расстановок скобок в выражении. Т.е. приоритет операций нам говорит, что `a / b / c - d == (a / b / c) - d`. Ассоциативность - что `(a / b / c) - d == ((a / b) / c) - d`.

Обратите внимание, что правила ассоциативности и приоритета ничего не говорят нам о том, в каком порядке нужно вычислять подвыражения `a`, `b`, `c` и `d`. Они говорят только о том, в каком порядке нужно выполнять операции над операндами, но не о порядке вычисления операндов.

А об этом говорит [правило порядка вычисления подвыражений](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.7):

> The Java programming language guarantees that the operands of operators appear to be evaluated in a specific evaluation order, namely, from left to right.

Весь ваш вопрос и замешательство связаны как раз с порядком вычисления подвыражений.

Для выражения `number + number * (number + ++number)` порядок вычислений подвыражений будет таким:

```
number + number * (number + ++number)
 ^         ^         ^          ^
 |         |         |          |
 1         2         3          4       -  порядок вычисления

 2     +   2    * (  2    +     3   )   ==   12
```

Теперь, что касается `a = 3; b = ++a + (a-- * ++a);`. Тут к написанному выше еще добавляется правило, что пре-(пост-) ин(де)кремент модифицирует переменную до(после) вычисления подвыражения.

```
a = 3;
b = ++a + (a-- * ++a);
      ^    ^       ^ 
      1    2       3        порядок вычисления подвыражений
                      
      4 + (4   *   4)       значение подвыражения
      4    3       4        значение а после вычисления подвыражения
```

Так что в результате будет `4 * (4 + 4)`.

> Почему еще у унарных операторов ассоциативность справа налево? Как это работает?

В выражениях типа `++ ++ a` и `- - 2` скобки согласно ассоциативности расставляются так `(++ (++ a))` и `(- (- 2))`, что ожидаемо и естественно, т.к. мы не можем применять оператор до того, как рассчитаем его аргумент.